# How to validate creditor id

Tags: php, regex

I am trying to write a regex for the creditor id. I know that the creditor id must look like this:

```
REGEX = %r{\A
//                        [a-zA-Z]{2}                 # ISO country code
//                        [0-9]{2}                    # Check digits
//                        [A-Za-z0-9]{3}              # Creditor business code
//                        [A-Za-z0-9+?/:().,'-]{1,28} # National identifier
//                      \z}x
```

I now converted this into php like:

```
preg_match("/([a-zA-Z]){2}\s*([0-9]){2}\s*([A-Za-z0-9]){3}\s*(([A-Za-z0-9\+|\?|/|\-|:|\(|\)|\.|,|'| ])){1,28}/", $_POST['creditor_id'])
```

Unfortunatly this is not working.

Do you have any hints?

Comment: Can you add to the question what you mean by "not working". What are the possible values of `$_POST['creditor_id']`?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you butchered a perfectly valid regex...

```php
preg_match(<<<'REGEX'
    {\A
        [a-zA-Z]{2}                 # ISO country code
        [0-9]{2}                    # Check digits
        [a-zA-Z0-9]{3}              # Creditor business code
        [a-zA-Z0-9+?/:().,'-]{1,28} # National identifier
    \z}x
REGEX, $_POST['creditor_id']);
```

This will work exactly like the original. PHP supports all of the features used in exactly the same syntax.

---

The reason why yours doesn't work, aside from the mangled character class that makes some characters valid that weren't supposed to be, is that you used `/` as the delimiter, *and* have an unescaped `/` in your character class, leading to an invalid regex expression.